How I determine numerically the pitch rate of an aircraft?
I have done aerodynamic analysis on a UAV. Is it possible to calculate pitch rate and yaw rate of my UAV depending on design parameters? (I have aerodynamic analysis of the wing, CL, CD, MAC, W, etc.)

What do you mean with "aerodynamic analysis"? Experimental or analytical?

steady state CFD

Well, then you just have to run two (or more, according to your resources) simulations with say two different aspect ratios and then compare the two results (in terms of pitch/roll rate)

You need to do a static maneuverability analysis.  This involves knowing the size of the control surfaces, calculating their effectiveness (which is not easy), some knowledge of the moments of inertia of the aircraft, etc.
In general, this is covered in textbooks on Stability and Control, alternatively, flight dynamics, or flight mechanics.  Roskam has a two-volume set, Etkin & Reid is another -- there are many to choose from.
